# SAS include another SAS script within a macro

Tags: sas

I am looking to include one sas program inside the macro written in another sas program.
So:

```
sas_prog1.sas:
data test;
a=1;
run;

sas_prog2.sas:

%macro m2;
%include sas_prog1.sas;
%mend;
%m2;
```

Does the data step in sas_prog1.sas also need to be wrapped inside a macro?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No - you don't need to. When you use an %include statement, it just essentially writes out all contents in the included file at that location. In your case it just dumps the datastep code and hence it effectively becomes:

```
%macro m2;
  data test;
   a=1;
  run;
%mend;

%m2;
```

So you should be good to go.

Answer (score 2):

you can include a code in another in writting it to a temp file as character.

```
filename exec_code temp;
data _null_;
  file exec_code;
  put ' your sas instruction'
  put 'your sas instruction'
run;
```

and in your macro use an include

```
%macro mymacro();

%include exec_code;

%mend;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that sas_prog1.sas is a being used as a module and you will have multiple modules for the entire code,  you can simply use a %include to execute the program. There is no need to execute it inside of a macro in  sas_prog2, but it can be.

contents of file saved as sas_prog1.sas:

```
data test;
    a=1;
    run;
```

contents of sas_prog2.sas:

```
%include "[prog_dir]\sas_prog2.sas";
```